Why not enter the "try catch", but throw an exception externally? And who is null?
Firstly，the CAN device receives message,and calling the following method
private List<string> recordList = new List<string>();//
private List<string> recordList1 = new List<string>();//
private List<string> recordList2 = new List<string>();//

 public void FrameReceived(CANFrame frame)
 {

     if (!isRecord) return;
     if (frame != null)
     {
         string record = RecordFrame(frame, "Rx");
         recordList.Add(record);
         if (frame.Channel == 1) recordList1.Add(record);
         if (frame.Channel == 2) recordList2.Add(record);
     }
 }

 public string RecordFrame(CANFrame frame, string type)
 {
     string text1 = string.Empty;
     if (frame.type == TPCANMessageType.PCAN_MESSAGE_STANDARD)
     {
         text1 = ($"{stopwatch.ElapsedTicks * 1.0 / Stopwatch.Frequency,11:#0.000000} {frame.Channel}  {frame.Id,-15:X} {type}   d {frame.Length} {frame.ToHexString()}");
     }
     else if (frame.type == TPCANMessageType.PCAN_MESSAGE_EXTENDED)
     {
         text1 = ($"{stopwatch.ElapsedTicks * 1.0 / Stopwatch.Frequency,11:#0.000000} {frame.Channel}  " + $"{frame.Id:X}x".PadRight(15) + $" {type}   d {frame.Length} {frame.ToHexString()}");
     }
     else if (frame.type == TPCANMessageType.PCAN_MESSAGE_FD)
     {
         text1 = ($"{stopwatch.ElapsedTicks * 1.0 / Stopwatch.Frequency:#0.000000} CANFD {frame.Channel} {type} {frame.Id:X} 0 0 1 {frame.DLC:X2} {frame.Length} {frame.ToHexString()} 0 0 39b5 0 0 0 0");
     }
     
     else
     {
         if (frame.Data.Length <= 8)
         {
             text1 = ($"{stopwatch.ElapsedTicks * 1.0 / Stopwatch.Frequency,11:#0.000000} {frame.Channel}  " + (frame.Id > 0x7FF ? $"{frame.Id:X}x".PadRight(15) : $"{frame.Id,-15:X}") + $" {type}   d {frame.Length} {frame.ToHexString()}");
         }
         else
         {
             text1 = ($"{stopwatch.ElapsedTicks * 1.0 / Stopwatch.Frequency:#0.000000} CANFD {frame.Channel} {type} " + (frame.Id > 0x7FF ? $"{frame.Id:X}x" : $"{frame.Id:X}") + $" 0 0 1 {frame.DLC:X2} {frame.Length} {frame.ToHexString()} 0 0 39b5 0 0 0 0");
         }
     }
     return text1;

 }

Then,I call follwing method to store the message
 public void StartRecord(string fileName)
 {
     this.fileName = fileName;
     stopwatch.Reset();
     stopwatch.Start();

     recordList.Clear();
     recordList1.Clear();
     recordList2.Clear();
     isRecord = true;
 }
 public void StopRecord()
 {
     isRecord = false;
     WriteToFile();
     
     stopwatch.Stop();

 }

private async void WriteToFile()
{
    try
    {
        Task writeAll = WriteToFileAsync($"{fileName}\\合并CAN.asc", new List<string>(recordList));
        Task write1 = WriteToFileAsync($"{fileName}\\内CAN.asc", new List<string>(recordList1));
        Task write2 = WriteToFileAsync($"{fileName}\\外CAN.asc", new List<string>(recordList2));
        await Task.WhenAll(writeAll, write1, write2);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        SmartFrameWork.Console.WriteLine("WriteToFile()");
        SmartFrameWork.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
async Task WriteToFileAsync(string fileName,List<string> lines)
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync($"date {DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")}");
            await writer.WriteLineAsync("base hex  timestamps absolute");
            await writer.WriteLineAsync("no internal events logged");
            await writer.WriteLineAsync($"//Version 5.6");
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                if (writer == null)
                    SmartFrameWork.Console.WriteLine("writer为空");
                if (line == null)
                    SmartFrameWork.Console.WriteLine("写入该行的内容为空");
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);

            }
            await writer.FlushAsync(); 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        SmartFrameWork.Console.WriteLine("WriteToFileAsync(string fileName,List<string> lines)");
        SmartFrameWork.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
   
}


the exception infomation:

System.NullReferenceException：未将对象引I用设置到对象的实例。 在
System.IO.StreamWriter.<WriteAsynclnternal>d_55.MoveNext()
---引发异常的上一位置中堆栈跟踪的末尾· 在
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
task) 在
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task) 在 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResulto 在
CANBusDriver.FileFrameFilter.<WriteToFileAsync>d_35.MoveNext() 位置
D:\Projects\HIL\HIL_
fanqingyu\V5.6Beta\HIL\CANdriver\FileFrameFilter.cs:行号157
--引发异常的上一位置中堆栈跟踪的末尾-- 在
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
task) 在
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task) 在 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 在
CANBusDriver.FileFrameFilter.<WriteToFile>d_34.MoveNext() 位置
D:\Projects\HIL\HIL_
fanqingyu\V5.6Beta\HIL\CANdriver\FileFrameFilter.cs:行号 145
--引发异常的上一位置中堆栈跟踪的末尾-- 在
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.≤ThrowAsync>b6_1(0bject
state) 在 System.Threading.QueueUserWorkltemCallback.WaitCallback_
Context(Object state) 在
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Runlnternal(ExecutionContext
executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
preserveSyncCtx) 在
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
executionContext,ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
preserveSyncCtx) 在
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkitemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkltem.ExecuteWorkltem()
在 System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() 在
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

the line 157 means "await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);" the line 145 means "await Task.WhenAll(writeAll, write1, write2);" This exception is an occasional occurrence, not a definite occurrence,according to the exception information,there is a NullReferenceException，and the exception rised by the statement "await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);" .I am sure the "line" is not null,because before i add it to the List,its initial value is string.Empty,but the "writer" has worked.the "ChatGPT" tells me it happend inside the method of"await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);",i can not understand `

This question is similar to: Task.WhenAll not throwing exception as expected. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Which of the two catch clauses are you referring to? Did you already use the Debugger to find the place where the NullReferenceException occurs?

the line 157  means "await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);"
the line 145 means "await Task.WhenAll(writeAll, write1, write2);"
This exception is an occasional occurrence, not a definite occurrence,according to the exception information,there is a NullReferenceException，and the  exception rised by the statement  "await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);" .I am sure the "line" is not null,because before i add it to the List,its initial value is string.Empty,but the "writer" has worked.the "ChatGPT" tells me it happend inside the method of"await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);",i can not understand

Can you please [edit] your question to add this additional information?

async void WriteToFile() - why is this not async Task? As it is now, this method cannot be awaited. How do you call it?

@KlausGütter i do not need its answer

Please also provide how WriteToFile() is being called

@FerryTo  now,I have added all the code

writer can't be null, but maybe line can be? I think you have a thread safety problem, you are changing many instance fields without any locking. Personally I would rewrite this, move all this stream writing code into a new class. Assign a single reference field to start / stop recording. Use a Channel<CANFrame> to queue the messages so they can be written in order, in a separate async method, without blocking. And so the logging can be streamed without keeping all the objects in memory.

@JeremyLakeman your idea is correct,the thread safety problem caused the line to be empty,I use three Task to add non-empty string to the my recordList,It turns out that it sometimes contains empty strings.
thanks!

you are passing wrong params for method WriteToFileAsync(filename, recordinglistobject_reference)
